# vertical equal sign

Tags: symbols

I am looking to create a vertical equal sign that might function similarly to an underbrace. I often use this symbol when taking notes on paper.

```
 (x+z) + (y+d) = 10
  ||      || 
  5       5
```

The alignment is not entirely perfect in this example but I believe the idea comes across.

Comment: You could also use `\underbrace{..}_{{}=5}`.

Comment: @Werner Yes that's functional but I'd personally prefer it with no braces and a rotated equals sign.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is another way of achieving this. You use the command `\equalto{equation}{value}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\verteq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,=$}}
\newcommand{\equalto}[2]{\underset{\scriptstyle\overset{\mkern4mu\verteq}{#2}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \equalto{(x + z)}{5} + \equalto{(y + d)}{5} = 10
\]

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, I added some spacing to the vertical equal manually (and some horizontal spacing to the `\equalto` command), of course, you can tweak both to get the exact output you want.

Comment: This has the right spaces around the equal signs, but reduces the size of the "5" which is incorrect -- the "5" shoul have the same size at the "10", which does not.

Comment: I found adding \displaystyle to the second argument of overset fixes the size problem, and I found the kerning unnecessary for my needs.

```
\newcommand{\verteq}[2]{
  \underset{
    \overset{
      \rotatebox{90}{$\,=$}
    }{\displaystyle{#2}}
  }{\displaystyle{#1}}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), I just found that if you are using `amsmath,amssymb` then you have access to `\shortparallel`

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\stackbelow#1#2{\underset{\displaystyle\overset{\displaystyle\shortparallel}{#2}}{#1}}

$$\stackbelow{(x+z)}{5}+\stackbelow{(y+d)}{5} = 10.$$
```

The result, obtained thanks to [quicklatex](https://quicklatex.com/):

[image: solution]

Comment: It is not really good because it differs too much from the horizontal equal sign right there on the equation.