# inequality sign vertically rotated

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to do a similar thing as in [vertical equal sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100538/vertical-equal-sign) but with an inequality sign instead.

I tried replacing `=` with `\ineq` in the line

```
\newcommand{\verteq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,=$}}
```

but could you please explain what is wrong in the approach?

Comment: `\newcommand{\vertneq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,\neq$}}`?

Comment: You should use `\neq`, that you'll find in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764).

Comment: @Werner: The rotation issues are not covered by the duplicate, therefore I wanted to write this as answer: `\usepackage{graphicx}    
\makeatletter    
\newcommand*{\vertneq}{%    
  \mathrel{%    
    \mathpalette{\math@rotate{90}}{\neq}%    
  }%    
}    
\newcommand*{\math@rotate}[3]{%    
  % #1: rotation angle    
  % #2: math style    
  % #3: symbol    
  \sbox0{$#2\vcenter{}$}% location of the math axis    
  \rotatebox[y=\ht0]{90}{$#2#3\m@th$}%    
}    
\makeatother`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: There is no mention of rotation issues in this post.

Comment: @Werner: The definitiono of `\verteq` looks quite odd with `\,`. Also `\verteq` is not a relational operator and it does not adapt in size according to the current math style.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Then you should add it to [vertical equal sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100538/5764), since that question deals with the rotation of an operator in its presentation.