# Is there a package to equate particular parts of an equation?

Tags: equations

Just wondering if there's a particular way to do the following in LaTeX:

[image]

where I've equated a particular part of the main equation to a little equation, given by *T* and *U*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! `amsmath` provides `\underbrace`, with usage `\underbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2}_{=T}`.

Comment: Related: [vertical equal sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100553/3345)

Comment: Schrödinger's equation ;-) .. The `^` above the potential operator is out of alignment. It should be over `U` only

Comment: @1010011010, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MikeRenfro, that's a useful addition, thank you!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought that too! Thank you for confirming. I'll move it in my document.

Comment: @HarrySmith: For the typesetting of the `ket`s  you might have  a look on the `braket` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh yes, that looks like a useful package. What is the benefit of using that over the commands: `\renewcommand{\b}[1]{\big\langle {#1} \big|}`, `\renewcommand{\k}[1]{\big| {#1} \big\rangle}`, `\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\big\langle {#1} \big| {#2} \big\rangle}`, `\newcommand{\expct}[1]{\big\langle {#1} \big\rangle}`, `\newcommand{\pamp}[1]{\big|#1\big|^2}`?

Comment: @HarrySmith: I think that package has been optimized for typesetting quantum mechanics calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. I've introduced a few commands to make it easier to typeset some parts of the equations in a more automated way, or if you wish to change something all over the document at once. *They're not strictly necessary for the obtained result.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/70hSYbF.png?1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\newcommand\partt[1][]{%
  \ifmmode
    \frac{\partial#1\mathstrut}{\partial t}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\ChristianHupfer[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \lvert
      #1%
    \rangle
  \fi
}
\newcommand\rotateequal[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \underset{#1}{\rotatebox{90}{$=$}}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\myvector[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathbf#1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\largemathstrut{%
  \ifmmode
    \frac{\mathstrut}{\mathstrut}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\[
i\hbar\partt\ChristianHupfer{\psi(\myvector{r},t)} 
= 
\underbrace{\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^2\largemathstrut}_{\rotateequal{T}}\ChristianHupfer{\psi(\myvector{r},t)}
+
\underbrace{\hat{U(\myvector{r})}\largemathstrut}_{\rotateequal{U}}\ChristianHupfer{\psi(\myvector{r},t)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\waveleft`?  ;-) That's a `ket` state vector

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fixed. :-)

Comment: This is a very nice solution. It's a shame the standard `\underbrace` curly brace symbol is so ugly!

Comment: What's the purpose of `\ifmmode` in all those definitions? If you use those commands in a wrong place you'll get nothing, instead of a clear error message (`Missing $ inserted`)

Answer (score 3):

Here, I provide `\undereq{}` to be used in the `\underbrace` subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\newcommand\undereq[1]{%
  \stackunder[2pt]{\mkern1mu\rotatebox{90}%
                  {$\scriptstyle=\mkern-3mu$}}{\scriptstyle \mathstrut#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  = \underbrace{\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2}_{\undereq{T}}\lvert \psi(\mathbf{r},t)...
\]\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this provides the right formatting for equations, the main body text now overlaps my headers. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @HarrySmith I'm not sure I understand.  When you say "headers," do you mean the stuff at the top of the page?  If so, I don't see how this particular implementation could produce that effect.

Comment: I am writing using the `book` class, with the `fancyhdr` package. It results in this: http://1drv.ms/1GToe1a.

Comment: @HarrySmith That web site is blocked to me, so I cannot see it.  However, using `book` class, `fancyhdr` package, with a `\pagestyle{fancy}` and a `\fancyhead{This is a test}` does not produce any interference with the header using my MWE.

Comment: Hosting shared files on OneDrive is less-than-ideal, haha. This one may work: http://1drv.ms/1H3EwqP.
However, I tried this solution in a regular document and it worked very nicely -- and the curly brace looks nice, too. I may use this in future documents. Thank you!

Comment: @HarrySmith The actual 1drv.ms site is blocked to me for security reasons, so a different file on the same site won't help me there.  I truly think the problem is an interaction between `book` and `fancyhdr`, which just happened to be activated through the large-height equation.

Answer (score 1):

A possible better way to set your equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{braket,graphicx}

\newcommand\pder[2][]{%
  \frac{\partial#1\mathstrut}{\partial #2}%
}

\newcommand\roteq{\mathpalette\doroteq\relax}
\newcommand\doroteq[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$#1=$}%
}

\renewcommand\vec[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\BF}{\vphantom{\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^2}} % just for this equation
i\hbar\pder{t}\ket{\psi(\vec{r},t)} 
= 
\underbrace{\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^2}_{\substack{\roteq\\T}}\ket{\psi(\vec{r},t)}
+
\underbrace{\BF\widehat{U(\vec{r})}}_{\substack{\roteq\\U}}\ket{\psi(\vec{r},t)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]